# Can an application be auto-raised only if no other applications are focused?

Tags: macos, display

So this is kind of a follow-up to [How do I make OS X auto focus on the window in the screen the mouse moves into?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87655/how-do-i-make-os-x-auto-focus-on-the-window-in-the-screen-the-mouse-moves-into) because I'm having a different problem but looking for slightly different functionality.

The answer to that question with window management software that make raised a window into focus if the mouse was stopped over it for awhile. I don't like that solution at all, because I will typically have a few windows open on one monitor. If I start writing in one window, but my mouse is resting over the corner of another window farther back, I don't want it to be raised to the front.

I'm looking for a specific type of functionality, but I don't know if it's possible. My main issue is that I use jiTouch to give me tons of gestures; they're my primary mode of navigation on my Mac. One set of gestures allows me to move left and right through my tabs on Chrome. However, if I have Chrome in fullscreen on one monitor and the another apps with tabs focused on the other monitor, I often move my mouse over the Chrome window and shift between tabs in the focused application rather than Chrome.

Is there a way to Auto Raise a window only no other windows on that particular monitor are already in focus? That is, if I move my cursor from Chrome to an application on my other monitor, the application it lands on will come into focus; if I then hover over another application on the same monitor, it won't be autoraised.