# Make mousing over a new window or screen change the focus to that window?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mouse, window-manager, dual-screen

I have a multi-monitor set up with my Macbook Pro. Frequently, when I move my mouse from one monitor to another, I'll assume I'm now working in the window my mouse is over, but find myself typing and having my old window/monitor accepting the input.

I've tried going to get the third party software site referenced in this previous question:

[How do I make OS X auto focus on the window in the screen the mouse moves into?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87655/how-do-i-make-os-x-auto-focus-on-the-window-in-the-screen-the-mouse-moves-into)

Unfortunately, the software they reference no longer exists

How can I change the focus just by moving the mouse?

Comment: This has come up quite often in the past, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=mouse+focus for a bunch of questions and answers on it.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer you've linked links to a piece of 3rd party software which no longer has a valid URL

In terms of the search, the top questions either have no answers or yet another answer where the software to do it no longer exists. Can we keep this open? The duplicates have no (valid) answers

Comment: Please edit the question to list the things you‘ve tried, and how they failed to solve the problem. This will put the question into the reopen queue for review.

Comment: Done. Hopefully that gets the ball rolling here